# What is this new device naming policy in linux?

Tags: wireless, sd-card

What is this mmcblk0p1 instead of sdb (sdc, etc)? Why an SD card is named mmc (as in mmc card)?
What is this wlp3s0 instead of ath0 (or eth0)? Why is a wifi card named wlp3 when i have only one wireless card?
What is this mumbo-jumbo? What's wrong with the old naming system?

Comment: Systemd is the cause.

Comment: This seems like a rant, more than a question.

Comment: Read this -> https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/ and the comments in https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L20

Comment: Thank you , Ron! Publish it and i'll accept it as answer. As a side comment, i really don't like this systemd policy much. It's like a static IP/identifier for every piece of software. Sometimes is good, and sometimes makes your hardware a sitting duck for malware attacks. The old naming system assured some level of anonymity.